# Huge difference between recorded time from "%%timeit" and actual time of computation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab, timeit

I used the magic command [`%%timeit`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) in a jupyter lab notebook.

The cell is composed of the following code:

```
%%timeit
scaler.fit(X_train)
grad.fit(scaler.transform(X_train),Y_train)
```

Where `grad` is a `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier` object, `X_train` a `numpy.matrix` of shape: (90757, 218), and `Y_train` a `numpy.array`. Just to say that it seems normal to be a long computation.

Well, I am very surprised to see `%%timeit` to give `9min 22s ± 6.01 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` while the cell was computed ( `[*]` you know what it means ) for about 1 hour. Note the information `9min 22s ± 6.01 s` only appears after the notebook declares the cell to be totally computed, so after `[*]` disappears.

Does it mean the notebook is lying when it declares this is still computing or does `%%timeit` turn crazy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [`%%timeit`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) runs the cell multiple times, reporting the average runtime at the end. If you want to measure wall-clock runtime for a block of code while running it just once, use [`%%time`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-time)